# Decoding this assembly inline code snippet on PowerPc

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, powerpc

I have this below code snippet from kernel source for PowerPc

```
#define SPRN_IVOR32     0x210   /* Interrupt Vector Offset Register 32 */

unsigned long ivor[3];
ivor[0] = mfspr(SPRN_IVOR32);

#define __stringify_1(x)        #x
#define __stringify(x)          __stringify_1(x)

#define mfspr(rn)       ({unsigned long rval; \
                    asm volatile("mfspr %0," __stringify(rn) \
                            : "=r" (rval)); rval; })
```

Also, it this above exercise is about emulating MSR register's bits in PowerPc?

Can anyone help me on what exactly we are doing here?

Comment: Compile this program and get preprocessor listing with macros resolved. This will be more readable.

Comment: The macros do make this a bit harder to read.  While I don't speak PowerPC, wouldn't this be somewhat easier to read/maintain as `#define mfspr(rn) ({unsigned long rval; asm volatile("mfspr %0,%c1" : "=r" (rval) : "i" (rn)); rval; })`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mfspr` macro generates an asm instruction `mfspr` which reads the given special purpose register into a register chosen by the compiler, which then gets assigned to `rval` hence becomes the return value of the expression.

As the comment says, `SPRN_IVOR32` is the `Interrupt Vector Offset Register 32`, whose contents are thus fetched into `ivor[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @Jester,One query,is this whole exercise is about emulating MSR register in PowerPC?

Comment: It's not emulating anything, it just provides a way to access the register from C.